# Once outlet removed others in separate room don’t work

Tags: receptacle

Doing a remodel in our formal dinning room and need to remove an outlet. Once outlet removed, outlets in other room don’t work. Once I reconnected the outlet other outlets worked. How do I remove the outlet without affecting the others?

Comment: are you removing the wall that has the outlet?

Answer (score 3):

Connect the wires as they were on the outlet (using wirenuts, or another approved connector type if preferred) and use a blank junction box cover over the box (you must leave the junction box cover accessible.)